# Google cloud datastore index size

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

From https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/storage-size#index_entry_size

Size of key = Size of kind name + Size of key string or Size of key numeric + 16 bytes

Size of index entry = Size of key + Size of indexed property(ies) + Size of kind name (for built in index) + 32 bytes

I would like to understand why Size of kind name is included separately in the index entry when it is already included as part of Size of key.